# how to stream a video using MPEG-DASH in GOLANG?

Tags: http, go, video, mpeg-dash, shaka

I have a go HTTP server and a video tag in `/watch.html`.

How can I stream a video using MPEG-DASH when someone visits the watch page and display the video using Shaka Player in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your visitors are using a web browser. Web browsers don't natively support playing MPEG-DASH. So you have to embed or reference a JavaScript based MPEG-DASH player.

You'll find many samples at https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/samples/index.html

or you can also use the Shaka player:

https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player